# Github workflow for base application

Tags: git, github, workflow, repository

I have a base application repo in Github. I'm about to add a new repo to my account that is going to use the base app... though I'd like to be able to merge updates from the base application to the new repo every time the base app gets updated. What would this workflow be?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I handle my mvc framework, the website programming, and the website config needed by the mvc framework.  It helps me to have the repos separate so I can easily make and track changes back to each repo.  The mvc framework is my base app in this case.  Please note the use of symbolic links to point to the other folders.

Example method of procedure:

```
mkdir app_name
cd app_name
git clone git@github.com:username/my_mvc.git mvc
git clone git@github.com:username/app_name_src.git src
git clone git@github.com:username/app_name_config.git config
cd mvc/
ln -s ../config/ config
ln -s ../src/ src
```

Example finished directory structure:

```
app_name/
  mvc/
    .git/
    .htaccess
    index.php
    libs/
     - view.php
     - session.php
     - model.php
     - database.php
     - controller.php
     - bootstrap.php
    config->../config
    src->../src
  src/
    .git/
    views/
     - index/
       - index.php
     - header.php
     - footer.php
    public/
     - javascript/
     - images/
     - css/
    models/
     - convertor_model.php
    controllers/
     - index.php
     - error.php
     - convertor.php
  config/
     .git/
     - database.php
     - paths.php
```